# Late-arriving packets in a real-time networked game environment

Tags: networking, synchronization, game-engine, multiplayer, lag

Let's say I have a real-time networked game with a fixed-time step. Let's also say that I managed to synchronize the current step across all clients and the server. If an input packet arrives to any host early, he can simply store it and wait for the right step to execute it. However, what happens if a packet arrives later? Example:

A packet timestamped for step 5 arrives which tells us that Player A kills Player B and thus A becomes a winner. However 2 steps later a late packet timestamped for step 4 arrives which tells us that Player B killed Player A. If the packet didn't arrive late, it was Player A who was going to lose the game. The only solution I can think of is to record history and go back and forth in time to impose corrections, but that might look extremely awkward in some cases.

What is the typical way to go about this? What should I do with packets which arrive late? On the server side it's easy - I can ignore their original timestamp and be authoritative (in fact I must do that in order to prevent cheating), but on the client sides that will cause desyncs between separate clients.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Stream Sockets for critical information like who killed whom. Stream Sockets uses TCP for data transmission and packets arrive always in same order for e.g if you send 'A, B, C' they will arrive in same order i.e. 'A, B' C'

For information like movement which is less important you can use Datagram sockets, they use UDP for data transmission. Here you can simply ignore the older messages as you have already processed the new movement.